# How to merge to cells of a column if the adjacent cells are consecutive blanks in python

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

[image]

I have two columns data. There are some rows where text data is spilled into the below row. I want to add that row data (4th row in df) to the above row.  Such that there should be alternate blanks in column 0.

Answer (score 0):

There might be pandas gods, who can do such a complex task directly in pandas data frame, but for us mortals better to take the data frame apart, work with standard Python data structures and merge them at the end.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=dict(
        id=[6.1, None, None, None, 6.2, None, None, 6.3, ],
        text=["t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7"]
    )
)


def create_merge_list(ids):
    """Creates a boolean list: whether the text needs to be merged to the previous text."""
    merge = []
    distance_from_last_id = 1
    for i in ids:
        if not is_id(i):
            distance_from_last_id = 0
        merge.append(distance_from_last_id >= 2)
        distance_from_last_id += 1
    return merge


def is_id(id_value):
    """Checks the value in the 0th column, whether it is an id there is no id"""
    return pd.isna(id_value)


def create_new_df(df):
    ids = df.iloc[:, 0]
    merge_list = create_merge_list(ids)
    # merge_list is here [False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False]

    texts = []
    new_ids = []
    old_texts = df.iloc[:, 1]
    for merge, text, i in zip(merge_list, old_texts, ids):
        if merge:
            texts[-1] += " " + text
        else:
            texts.append(text)
            new_ids.append(i)
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=dict(
            Id=new_ids,
            text=texts
        )
        )

print(df)
# 0  6.1   t0
# 1  NaN   t1
# 2  NaN   t2
# 3  NaN   t3
# 4  6.2   t4
# 5  NaN   t5
# 6  NaN   t6
# 7  6.3   t7

print(create_new_df(df))
#     Id      text
# 0  6.1        t0
# 1  NaN  t1 t2 t3
# 2  6.2        t4
# 3  NaN     t5 t6
# 4  6.3        t7
```